# why is the Bundle ID of Kudan invlid?

Tags: kudan

error:Your Native API Key is INVALID for Bundle ID: eu.kudan.ar

why did this error happened?
I have already input the correct ID from the website...

https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,I just find my  Framework Version is 1.4.It needs another API License Key.
It is"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".

Comment: Are you using version 1.4.1? I am using this version, changed package name to "eu.kudan.ar", added the key you mentioned but still got "Your API key is not valid" message